# Where will the positive charge shift in the E1 mechanism of dehydration of an alcohol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, elimination

[image]

My Attempt:  according to me the double bond should be in position no. 2 but the correct answer has a double bond in position no.1. Why is it so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Benzene ring in itself is a stable structure. But double bond at position `2` will definitely destruct the stability of benzene ring. While being on position `1`, a double bond will be created on adjacent carbon to benzene ring which ultimately distributes the electron cloud more over the structure, leading to more stability.